# Erro ao tentar criptografar com BCRYPT no Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bcrypt

Codigo:

```
import bcrypt
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw('teste',bcrypt.gensalt())
```

erro:

> TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Ao rodar o programa apresenta esse erro, como posso resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O parâmetro deve ser do tipo `bytes`, você pode chamar ele de duas formas, dando um cast pra `bytes`

```
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(b'teste',bcrypt.gensalt())
```

ou usando um encoding:

```
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw('teste'.encode("utf-8"),bcrypt.gensalt())
```